# onreadystatechange function is not working in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

as far as XMLHttpRequest() Object is concerned, it is fine, the problem is with **onreadystatechange** for example if I put my code this way, it works perfect.

```
function process(){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(xmlHttp){
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            theD = document.getElementById("theD");
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 1){
                theD.innerHTML += "Status 1: Server connection established ! <br/>";
            }
            else if(xmlHttp.readyState == 2){
                theD.innerHTML += "Status 2: Request recieved ! <br/>";
            }
            else if(xmlHttp.readyState == 3){
                theD.innerHTML += "Status 3: Processing Request ! <br/>";
            }
            else if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){

                if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
                    var text = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    theD.innerHTML += "Status 4: Processing Request ! <br/>";
                    theD.innerHTML += text;
                }
                else{
                    alert("Something is wrong !");
                }
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "hello.txt", true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
}
```

but if I make a function of **handleServerResponse()**

```
function handleServerResponse(){
    theD = document.getElementById("theD");
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 1){
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 1: Server connection established ! <br/>";
    }
    else if(xmlHttp.readyState == 2){
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 2: Request recieved ! <br/>";
    }
    else if(xmlHttp.readyState == 3){
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 3: Processing Request ! <br/>";
    }
    else if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){

        if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
            var text = xmlHttp.responseText;
            theD.innerHTML += "Status 4: Processing Request ! <br/>";
            theD.innerHTML += text;
        }
        else{
            alert("Something is wrong !");
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();
```

It doesn't work. Please point it if I'm wrong.

Comment: why so much fuss..Use `$.ajax` instead..

Comment: change it to this - xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;

Answer (score 8):

try using

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
```

Note the removed paranthesis.

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "hello.txt", true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
xmlHttp.send();
```

As you see, I removed the parentheses and I inverted the order of `open` and `onreadystatechange`.

The first thing, is because otherwise you do not associate the function reference itself, but the function's return value – because, basically, you're executing it. It's the same difference to have:

```
var a = sum(1, 2); // 3, assign to `a` the return value of `sum`
var b = sum; // assign to `b` the `sum` function ref.
var c = b(1, 2); // 3, therefore `b` is an 'alias' to `sum`
```

The second thing, it depends by the browser: for instance, some version of IE "reset" the `onreadystatechange` of a `XMLHttpRequest` instance, every time the `open` method is called. So if you set the `onreadystatechange` before the `open`, that works as "initializator", there is a chance, depends by the browser, that would be removed – and therefore never called – once the `open` method is called.
So to be fully compatible, it's better set the `onreadystatechange` after the `open` method – but of course before the `send`.

Answer (score 1):

use this   `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse`

then write  as function handleServerResponse(xmlHttp)  it will work

Comment: Can you please elaborate why this would work? I encountered the same problem, but this did not solve the problem. It would be usefull to know why this is different from an inline function

Comment: handleServerResponse(); would be a call to the function.
In the case of xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse  you are setting a reference to the memory address of handleServerResponse   so that something else can call it.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is kind of old, but I just spent a couple of hours trying to make a similar program work in Chrome.

The only way that I could make it work was to use the `this` object.

Using a global `xmlHttp` instead of `this` results in the `handleServerResponse()` to be called only once when `xmlHttp.readyState == 2`.

Here is the code that works in Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (32-bit).

`handleServerResponse()` gets called 4 times, each time `xmlHttp.readyState` gets incremented.

Found by using Developer Tools in Chrome and monitoring the `this` object, amongst others.

```
function process(){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(xmlHttp){
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "hello.txt", true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    theD = document.getElementById("theD");
    if(this.readyState == 1){
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 1: Server connection established ! <br/>";
    }
    else if(this.readyState == 2){
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 2: Request recieved ! <br/>";
    }
    else if(this.readyState == 3){
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 3: Processing Request ! <br/>";
    }
    else if(this.readyState == 4){

        if(this.status == 200){
            var text = this.responseText;
            theD.innerHTML += "Status 4: Processing Request ! <br/>";
            theD.innerHTML += text;
        }
        else{
            alert("Something is wrong !");
        }
    }
}
```